# Try/Catch For File Not Found Exception Nested inside a While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to code for a file not found exception in a while loop so that the program continues prompting the user for the file (test.txt). I wrote a try/catch block inside a while loop. However, when I delete the input file (test.txt), the program should catch this error and print "Error, cannot locate the 'test.txt' file, please try again:" and allow the user to input another file name. However, the program crashes and gives me a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: it works fine in my pc.Have you restart your app after file deleted ?

Comment: `Input file name (from your computer): abc

***** ERROR *****

Cannot locate the input file 'abc'on your computer - please try again.

Input file name (from your computer):`

Comment: I think it's returning that error message because abc =/= test_input.txt because when I tell it to find the correct file, it crashes.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `FileNotFoundError` in the JDK. Do you mean `FileNotFoundException`? That can be thrown from `new Scanner(...)` or `new PrintWriter(...)`, not just inside your loop. The stack trace will tell you which. Unclear what you're actually asking here, or what the purpose of all this code is.

Comment: I want the program to catch the FileNotFoundException and then, instead of crashing, prompt the user to enter a file name until the user inputs the correct file.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, two lines raise `FileNotFoundException`s that you are not catching:

```
// scanner and printwriter objects for reading text file
Scanner in = new Scanner(correctInputfile);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputName);
// read input (values) and write the output (average)
```

You can replace them with the following, and the code (should) work.

```
Scanner in = null;// Initialize to null, so they don't raise warnings.
PrintWriter out = null;
try { // Surround with try/catch to get the exception
    in = new Scanner(correctInputfile);
    out = new PrintWriter(outputName);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    /*TODO: something about the exception here!
      Make sure the Scanner and PrintWriter get 
      properly initialized with valid file names.*/
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your response. I deleted the file before I ran the program.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `FileNotFoundError` in the JDK.

Comment: Such thing was specified in the question itself as the received error, though. I'll update the answer once I get to run the code, since it doesn't seem to be about that.

Comment: I've updated the answer to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's probably better to ask for permission rather than forgiveness (e.g. check if the file exists before attempting to read it).

```
File file = new File("test_input.txt");
if (file.exists()) {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
}
```

Comment: No it isn't. `File.exists()` doesn't 'ask for permission', and it only returns a `boolean`. There is far more information in a `FileNotFoundException`. And this practice forces the file system to search for the file twice. And there is still a timing-window problem. Not recommended at all.

Comment: That's a colloquialism related to exception handling, not necessarily permissions. There certainly is a race condition related to this approach, but given the original question it seems the solution would meet their needs. There are also various other IOExceptions that could occur while attempting to read the file, but to me that kind of detail is out of the scope of the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add another try and catch for the Scanner

```
// prompt user for name for output textfile
System.out.println();
System.out.print("What would you like to call your output file: ");
String outputName = inputReader.nextLine();
// scanner and printwriter objects for reading text file
try {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(correctInputfile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputName);
    // read input (values) and write the output (average)

    // messages triggered by successful location of files.
    if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(("test_input.txt"))) {
        // code logic
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("***** ERROR *****");
    System.out.println("\nCannot locate the input file " + "'" + fileName + "'" + "on your computer - please try again.");
    System.out.print("\nInput file name (from your computer): ");
}
```